# How to use regexp in Vapor Fluent sqlite?

Tags: swift, sqlite, vapor, vapor-fluent, server-side-swift

I have a simple model that has a string field, like this:

```swift
final class Record: Model, Content {
    
    @ID(key: .id)
    var id: UUID?

    @Field(key: "name")
    var name: String

    ...
}
```

And I want to query and filter this `name` field using a regexp pattern.

My current solution is using `.all()` to get all rows, then use normal `NSRegularExpression` way to filter every row in Swift.

However this is REALLY SLOW. On my machine I can do around 400 requests per second using the ORM framework provided `.filter()` functions. While only 4 request per second with my own regex filter.

I know that sqlite does provide a `REGEXP` function, and it's significantly faster. But it requires loading an external module to run.

So how can I import this module using FluentSQL or is there any workaround?

Comment: SQLite3 supports the REGEXP operator: `WHERE x REGEXP <regex>` so with Fluent you can filter by custom `REGEXP` operator easily.

Comment: @imike Some SQLite3 distribution does not include REGEXP operator by default, like the Ubuntu install which I am using. I installed `sqlite3-pcre` via `apt-get`, then I can use `REGEXP` in command line after `.load /usr/lib/sqlite3/pcre.so`. But I don't know how to do this in Fluent.

Comment: Similar to this `.filter(\.$name, .custom("ILIKE"), "earth")` which is written here https://docs.vapor.codes/4.0/fluent/advanced/